# Nextjs component Element type is invalid, expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to find a away to store icons in an array as object so that I can conditionally show the icons with a map function  when user hovers however when I try to do this I get error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {react, nextjs, tailwind}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I've tried to do this various different ways and I always get one of these error messages. What's the best approach? So that I can achieve my goal of revealing the stack object when card component is hovered. The hovering functionality is getting handled by Framer Motion. I have two files a Card.js component:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const Card = ({ image, title, description, stack }) => {
  const cardVariants = {
    hover: {
      scale: 1.05,
      transition: { duration: 0.3 },
    },
    initial: {
      scale: 1,
      transition: { duration: 0.3 },
    },
  };

  const imageVariants = {
    hover: {
      filter: "blur(10px)",
      transition: { duration: 0.3 },
    },
    initial: {
      filter: "blur(0px)",
      transition: { duration: 0.3 },
    },
  };

  const textVariants = {
    hover: {
      opacity: 1,
      y: 0,
      transition: { duration: 0.3 },
    },
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: 50,
      transition: { duration: 0.3 },
    },
  };

  const stackVariants = {
    hover: {
      opacity: 1,
      transition: { duration: 0.3 },
    },
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      transition: { duration: 0.3 },
    },
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      className="rounded-md shadow-md overflow-hidden relative"
      variants={cardVariants}
      initial="initial"
      whileHover="hover"
    >
      <motion.img
        className="w-full object-cover"
        src={image}
        alt={title}
        variants={imageVariants}
      />

      <motion.div className="p-2" variants={textVariants}>
        <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold">{title}</h3>
        <p className="text-gray-600">{description}</p>
        <motion.div
          variants={stackVariants}
          className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 pb-2 pt-4 bg-white"
        >
      
        </motion.div>
      </motion.div>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

And my Projects.js  file is the front end section where I am displaying cards that mapped from the data in listProject array :

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";

import DiNextjs from "react-icons/di";
import FaReact from "react-icons/fa";
import SiTailwindcss from "react-icons/si";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import Card from "./Card";

const Project = ({
  listProject = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Ecommerce",
      image: "/assets/auto.webp",
      stack: { react: FaReact, nextjs: DiNextjs, tailwind: SiTailwindcss },
      description: "lorem ipsumsd as dff asqqq weer",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Ecommerce",
      image: "/assets/auto.webp",
      stack: { react: FaReact, nextjs: DiNextjs, tailwind: SiTailwindcss },
      description: "lorem ipsumsd as dff asqqq weer",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Ecommerce",
      image: "/assets/og.webp",
      stack: { react: FaReact, nextjs: DiNextjs, tailwind: SiTailwindcss },
      description: "lorem ipsumsd as dff asqqq weer",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "Ecommerce",
      image: "/assets/down.webp",
      stack: { react: FaReact, nextjs: DiNextjs, tailwind: SiTailwindcss },
      description: "lorem ipsumsd as dff asqqq weer",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: "Ecommerce",
      image: "/assets/porsh.webp",
      stack: { react: FaReact, nextjs: DiNextjs, tailwind: SiTailwindcss },
      description: "lorem ipsumsd as dff asqqq weer",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      title: "Ecommerce",
      image: "/assets/web1.webp",
      stack: { react: FaReact, nextjs: DiNextjs, tailwind: SiTailwindcss },
      description: "lorem ipsumsd as dff asqqq weer",
    },
    // 
  ],
}) => {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);
  const [sliderRef, setSliderRef] = useState(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setIsMobile(window.innerWidth < 768);
    };
    handleResize(); // initial check
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  const firstRow = listProject.slice(0, 3);
  const secondRow = listProject.slice(3, 6);

  const sliderSettings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  };

  if (isMobile) {
    return (
      <div className="w-full">
        <Slider
          {...sliderSettings}
          dots={true}
          arrows={false}
          ref={setSliderRef}
        >
          {listProject.map((project) => (
            <Card
              key={project.id}
              image={project.image}
              title={project.title}
              description={project.description}
            />
          ))}
        </Slider>
        {/* Your slider controls */}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <section className="bg-gray-100">
      <div className="container mx-auto px-5 py-2 lg:px-32 lg:pt-12">
        <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-2 md:-mx-4">
          {listProject.map((project, index) => {
            if (index < 6) {
              return (
                <div
                  key={project.id}
                  className="w-full md:w-1/3 px-2 md:px-4 mb-4 md:mb-8"
                >
                  <div className="min-h-max">
                    <Card
                      key={project.id}
                      image={project.image}
                      title={project.title}
                      description={project.description}
                      stack={project.stack}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            }
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Project;
```

Comment: Does the current code throw any errors?

Comment: This doesn't look like it should be throwing any errors since it's not consuming the stack property. Please include any code you've tried, I suspect the issue is not instantiating them as React components.

Comment: Yes current code throws : Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.